# Excel INT equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am looking for the C# equivalent of the following Excel formula:

```
(INT(((4800/1000)/0.415)*2.393)/0.05)
```

I get the value `540` with the above formula in Excel, but now I am trying to do the same in C# with the following code:

```
Math.Round((((4800 /1000) / 0.415) * 2.393) / 0.05, 0)
```

I get the value `553`.

How can I get the same value with my C# coding?

Comment: Why don't you convert to an `Int` instead of trying to `Round`? Also, all those parentheses unrelated to the function call are unnecessary.

Comment: If i use your c# example, i get `461` not `553`.

Comment: Consider your innermost expression, and the difference between evaluating `4800/1000` in Excel and in C#.

Comment: I evaluated `4800 / 1000 / 0.415 * 2.393 / 0.05` in Python3 interpreter and also got 553 as a result. I think Excel is playing tricks on you. C# code looks ok, though messy.

Comment: Interestingly, I evaluated this in LibreOffice Calc, and it gave me `553.5614457831` as the result without the `INT`, and `553` when using `INT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what you need:

```
(int)(((4800.0 /1000) / 0.415) * 2.393) / 0.05
```

Or alternatively:

```
(int)((((double)4800 / 1000) / 0.415) * 2.393) / 0.05
```

The problem is that the 4800 and 1000 literals are interpreted as integers, and in C# dividing two integers yields you another rounded integer. So 4800/1000 = 4, but you want 4.8.

By adding the `.0` part you are implicitly converting the literal to a double, or you can also do an explicit cast. Dividing a double by an integer already gives you a double.

Comment: @Koamiman Thank you for the answer! What value did you get with the formula that you used above? I still get 553 with the method that you used :(

Comment: @CareTaker22 Are you sure? I am getting 540 with both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine((int)((((double)4800 / 1000) / 0.415) * 2.393) / 0.05);
    }
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/ESOGmZ)**

Integer divided by Integer(4800/1000) results in a integer(4) as against the excel result(4.8) which you are getting as double. So you need to cast it to double.

Comment: "Try this" doesn't explain what the actual issue with the code is.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi Thanks for the comment! I still get the value of 553 with the answer that you  gave

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Excel has rounded the answer of

```
((4800 /1000) / 0.415) * 2.393
```

first - so this is 27 then when you divide it by 0.05 it comes up with the answer of 540.

As for the C# working... Konamiman is correct that there is some int rounding going on. You can cast them as doubles or add .0 at the end to indicate these aren't ints:

```
Math.Round((((4800.0 / 1000.0) / 0.415) * 2.393) / 0.05, 0);
```

If you do this on using calc it shows that the C# calc (once you have them being treated as doubles) is correct:

[image]

**EDIT:**

From your comment you want to round the first part of the equation to use the integer part.

You can use Math.Floor for that returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

```
double d = ((4800.0 / 1000.0) / 0.415) * 2.393;
// d = 27.678...
double d1 = Math.Floor(d);
// d1 = 27
double d2 = d / 0.05;
// d2 = 540
```

**Note** - Be careful with the last line... if you use a divisor other than something where the reciprocal is a pure integer you won't get a round number for d2. So you might need to use Math.Round or Math.Floor on d2 to fix that... all depends on whether 0.05 will ever change.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! :) I am looking for the value of 540 in c# though. Maybe I just misunderstood your answer?